# How to design a 3GHz antenna?

Tags: antenna, design, specifications, antenna-array

I would like to design a 3GHz high gain antenna.  S11 has to be below -10dB and the gain to be above 9dBi - and I want to make it smaller than 8cm.

What kind of antenna is better to satisfy the condition?

It doesn't matter about the antenna type, but I hope it will be a patch antenna.

Please recommend an antenna specification.

Comment: So you want a high-gain antenna (9dB) where the wavelength is 10cm. Do Yagis perform well?

Comment: What are you going to do with the antenna?  Why aren't commercial antennas acceptable?  Have you looked for commercially available antennas to see what is possible?